# How to find out who accessed a document?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, security

I got a call today from a friend asking for help, it is not my area, he is from a school, it is a big institution.

They have 2 windows 2003 server sp 1, one for MS Sql and the other is Domain controller.

The internal network is based on Windows XP sp 3.

There is a linux firewall and proxy for the internet in a separated machine.

The problem is that someone apparently could get access to a coordinator PC where the exams were prepared and copied the file.

They determined that by the following:

- suddenly a group of few students raised their points in exams in 80%
- a question trap were introduced on another exam and this same group answered according the trap

The problem is that the sysadmin maybe involved.

I got access to the network and to the main admin account. What i need to find out:

- find out who remotely logged in on the coordinator PC
- get the log of usage of the admin account in overall (that could be the account used to enter the coordinator PC)

Looks like all the computers are not sharing folders. There are antivirus working, a good blocking of websites.

I am not from this area and I am trying to help. Any other directions on track what happen.

Comment: Well without any auditing enabled on the machines it isn't going to be easy to tell. You can check the logins from the security event log on the PC that holds the files but again if its an admin account then this really doesn't prove who done it...

Comment: Might be easier to lay a trap and catch the guy in the act.

Comment: No personal offense to you OP, but it doesn't sound like you know enough to be the one investigating this for them.

Comment: @TheCleaner you right. no offense. but this is not a big deal either, and wanted to get the obvious out of the sight first. I want to eliminate the sysadmin, and He has full access, a trusted person, he has no concerns about protection, even of his own steps. If I can eliminate this, we can hire someone capable.

Comment: Just lean on the kids to spill who it was.

Comment: The problem is, you don't want to be speculating on something like this where students and staff could be suspended/disciplined/etc.  If you give even an opinion on this the school could take it as a qualified expert opinion and run with it.  You are better off telling them to hire a firm to do this.  You might be wanting to help, but there are legalities involved that you don't want to accidentally end up involved in.

Comment: @eelias My personal view on this is that the kids in question are involved in creative problem solving, and should not necessarily be punished for this.  If you ask me (not that the administration ever did, mind you), the kids should be applauded for their creativity, made to knock it off, and offered options to put their technical capabilities to more constructive use.  Just a thought...

Comment: @TheCleaner thank you for the advice. I will think about that. But down here in Brazil things are not even 10% of you have on US about law enforcement and suing someone is so slow and expensive and complicated that most of the time is not done. What happens is that when someone is doing wrong is just fired with no explanations, pay everything, say goodbye, see you.

Comment: @HopelessN00b good. They are not going to hunting down kids. They are not the problem here i believe. The problem is validate if this is internal, and the family style method of running this private school, they are more concerned on solve the relationship issue. No sue, no harsh. Of course things will be changed and security starting to be taken seriously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If auditing is enabled you could probably find SOMETHING in the security logs of the computer that was accessed.  If they want to try to catch them later on, they need to enable audit logs.  To do that, right click on the drive, folder, or even the file you want to audit, select properties, advanced settings, auditing tab.  click add, type in "users" and then check read data, or just check everything in the successful field. click ok, ok, ok.

Anytime anyone does anything that fulfills that access criteria there will be a log of the activity in the logs.

So from this you will be able to determine which security principal accessed the file at which time.

This doesn't mean that this person is the person leaking the data, however, as it's possible someone was able to compromise a password in the environment.

You could also enable detailed logging on the linux firewall (this is more proprietary) and cross reference the file accesses with the firewall logs to see what IP might be causing the issue.  Of course that's not the end-all either since they could be going through a few proxies themselves.

Comment: thanks, we will be preparing a honeypot and your suggestion will be used. We are actually trying to eliminate the possibility of the current sysadmin. I don't believe in very advanced tricks used to get this.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really do this retroactively.

The way this is usually done is to set up [file audit logging](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771070.aspx) on the files or folders you're interested in monitoring, which results in events being written to the Security Event Log based on the conditions you define, and include details that help you determine the person behind the access attempt (like the account used to access the file and the remote IP, for the most obvious examples).

Given that this isn't turned on by default, as it generates massive amounts of logs - our audit logs do almost 500 MB per machine per day, you probably don't have those in place currently, and won't be able to definitely prove historical access.  The best you'll be able to do is set them up going forward and catch anyone who uses them in the future.

That said, two things:

1. If it's not supposed to be viewable by everyone, it shouldn't be accessible to everyone.
   In the case of files, that can be anything from establishing an ACL so that only authorized people have permissions to view the file to encryption ("password protecting" Office documents, for example, or BitLocker encryption, or any number of 3rd party solutions) to more drastic measures, like keeping the materials offline when not in active use.
2. If you suspect an admin is involved, you've got your work cut out for you.  I can edit system logs (they're just plain text, after all), use accounts that aren't linked to me, and otherwise use my administrative access to do anything I want, with enough effort.  Not to mention, he'll be able to see that audit logging is enabled, if he bothers to look.  Unless he gets lazy or sloppy, he'll be impossible to catch... fortunately, that seems to happen in the vast majority of cases, so your odds aren't that long.  Having said that, if you're trying to catch a technically skilled individual abusing their administrative privileges, it really helps if you have some technical chops of your own.  In this case, that might mean covertly bringing in outside help.

Comment: thanks, the 2 option is the concerning one. What is happening is that this place is like a family owned company. The admin is not of the family, but close. He is not very skilled, most of the stuff in place were installed based on the wizard default. Since their main security is based on physical access. The admin is also a kind of relaxed person. not very careful.

Answer (score 0):

> **The problem is that someone apparently could get access to a coordinator PC where the exams were prepared and copied the file.**

I think it's pretty obvious how they did it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_UqEg1cFqig

[image]

Comment: +1 I think thecleaner is making a good serious point here even if it's being done in a flippant way. Also, I loved wargames...